# Difference between two conditional queries on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to find records based on two conditions on a data frame `preg`

First:

```
preg[preg.caseid==2298 & preg.pregordr==1]
```

This throws and error that truth value of a series is ambiguous.
Why?

Second:
But this one works!

```
preg[(preg.caseid==2298) & (preg.pregordr==1)]
```

So what exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it thinks that you're doing `2298 & preg.pregordr` something like that, without parenthesis you can do:

```
preg[preg.caseid.eq(2298) & preg.pregordr.eq(1)]
```

Comment: @jezrael Yeah i explained a bit